# JQuery - error with element non-focusable / how to force blur?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html form which uses jquery focus and blur in order to clear and restore some preset field text. However, the form is in a modal dialog which can be hidden and shown using jquery hide() and show(). However, when the form is hidden, it is throwing a javascript error:

```
an invalid form control with name = 'email' is not focusable
```

I'm assuming this is because the form is hidden and can't be accessed. Is there a way to force a blur event? Or some way to resolve this error? Here's my code:

```
$j('.dField').focus(function(){
    clearInput($j(this)[0]); //The [0] seems to be necessary to retrieve the element at the DOM object level
});
$j('.dField').blur(function(){
    restoreInput($j(this)[0]);
});

function clearInput(textField) {
    if (textField.value == textField.defaultValue) {
        textField.value = "";
     }
}

//Restores the default value
function restoreInput(textField){
    if (textField.value == ""){
        textField.value = textField.defaultValue;
    }
}

$j('#dFormBack').click(function(){
        $j('#dContentContainer').show();
        $j('#vehicle_form').hide();
    });
```

Comment: The `[0]` is equivalent to `.get(0)`. It retrieves the underlying DOM element at the specified position in the jQuery object. http://api.jquery.com/get/

Comment: Side note: did you try using the placeholder attribute instead (and possibly a placeholder plugin for compability)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to when you talk about a placeholder plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can activate the function inside the `blur` event listener, instead of trying to initiate a blur event.

```
restoreInput($j(".dfield")[0]);
```

A side note, your first lines can be written more efficiently:

```
$j('.dField').focus(function(){
    clearInput(this);
}).blur(function(){
    restoreInput(this);
});
```

`this` in the event handler refers to the DOM element to which the event listener is attached. It's unnecessary to wrap `this` inside a JQuery wrapper and get the DOM element again using `[0]`.

Comment: I can't use your code above, because each field with that class has a unique value, so the $(this) is necessary. But thanks for the code shortening, that's useful

Comment: Adjust the selector to match the relevant input element:`restoreInput($j(".dfield#email")[0]);`.

Comment: I don't really understand what referencing a specific field will do to solve this problem - and even if I take care of email field, there are four others to worry about

Comment: Call `restoreInput($j(".dfield#ID_HERE")[0]);` for each input element to achieve your desired results. Normally, the `blur` function executes these functions for each element. Now, you "manually" call these functions in order to get it work.

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](http://api.jquery.com/focus/):

> Triggering the focus on hidden elements causes an error in Internet Explorer. Take care to only call .focus() without parameters on elements that are visible.

So you should just check if the element is hidden before calling `focus()`

Comment: What would that code look like - everything I try doesn't seem to work. You can't put a conditional inside the focus listener, calling blur doesn't seem to work. Also, it's not just an IE issue - it's any browser.

Comment: Not inside the focus listener, do the check before the focus trigger.

Comment: Yeah - but the thing is - once you trigger a listener for focus, it persists unless you unbind the listener, right? At least it seems to for me

Comment: The error is raised when you are triggering focus() somewhere, right?

Comment: Yeah - it triggers when I click the close button - apparently, even if I try to call blur() on any form field, if your cursor is in a field already, it will attempt to call focus again, but by that point the form is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. When something is not visible, it cannot be `focus()`'ed or `blur()`'ed.